# How Android NDK cmakelist.txt output prebuilt library

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

Here is part of my `CMakeList.txt`.

```
add_library(
        pre-lib
        SHARED
        IMPORTED
)
set_target_properties(
        prelib
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        xxx
)
```

As you see, I import a shared library called `pre-lib` from outside. Now I want to target it with my own library.

```
target_link_libraries(
        mylib
        pre-lib
)
```

Everything works well and NDK generates `mylib.so` for me. But `mylib.so` needs `pre-lib.so`, right? **So how can Android NDK cmakelist.txt output prebuilt library.**

(Maybe `export` is more suitable ?)

## EDIT

The target  `mylib` is generated by `add_library(....)`.

Comment: Android Studio 3.0 and higher will pack both libraries to your APK.

Comment: This should be general CMake question and there is nothing NDK specific. Do you want to just link to pre-lib or build as pre-build step. You can use "include_directories" or "find_library". Also not clear if you are building excutable or only .so here.